# How to edit my postgreSQL query to select the most recent row by date for several columns

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query where I'm trying to select the most recent row based on date. So what I would like my query to do is to select the most recent datapoints for a couple columns in my database.

```
sql = f"""SELECT DISTINCT ON (id), cast(marketcap as money), cast(week52high as money), cast(week52low as money)
                 , to_char(dividend_yield * 100, '99D99%%')
                 , pe_ratio, ROUND(beta,2) 
          FROM security_stats 
          WHERE security_stats.id IN ({placeholders});
       """
```

For anyone wondering, `placeholders` is just a list of stocks given by the user.

The goal of this application is to retrieve the most recent observations for financial data points. My query works fine but instead it selects all of the rows per stock, when I just want the the most recent row, per stock.

How can I edit my query to fix the above? I have tried some methods using `MAX` and `LIMIT` but couldn't get it to work!.

EDIT:
Note that the columns working with are `id` and `date`. These should be distinct, and the date should be the most recent observation.

Got it to work thanks to @GME, using this method below. Special thanks too @ Somy for showing me another method as well!

```
sql = f"""SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, cast(marketcap as money), cast(week52high as money), cast(week52low as money)
                 , to_char(dividend_yield * 100, '99D99%%')
                 , pe_ratio, ROUND(beta,2) 
          FROM security_stats 
          WHERE security_stats.id IN ({placeholders}) ORDER BY id, date desc ;
       """
```

Comment: Which column stores the *stock*? And which one defines the *most recent* row?

Comment: totally forgot to add that, how silly. I use column `id` for the stock names, and column `date` for date. I updated my OG post to reflect my new attempt using the bottom suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column (or set of columns) in the `distinct on` clause defines the groups: if you want one row per "stock", then column *stock* should belong to that clause.

Then, you need an `order by`: it starts with the `distinct on` column(s), followed by one or more columns that define which row should be kept in each group: this is where the "date" column goes.

Your question does not explain what are the names of these to crucial columns in the table. Assuming that we have `id` and `date`, the logic would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) ...
FROM security_stats 
WHERE ...
ORDER BY id, date desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the id column is the key column which is equivalent to stock (as described in the question) - you may use windows function as below -

```
sql = f"""SELECT DISTINCT id, cast(marketcap as money), cast(week52high as money), cast(week52low as money)
                 , to_char(dividend_yield * 100, '99D99%%')
                 , pe_ratio, ROUND(beta,2)
          from 
          (Select t.*, 
                 row_number() over(partition by id order by date desc) as seq_num  
               FROM security_stats t
               WHERE t.id IN ({placeholders})) sst
          WHERE sst.seq_num = 1;
       """
```

Comment: Copied and pasted your code, getting an error in the query

Comment: Yes, I realised and edited it. Missed the from clause and made one more edit just now. Please try it now.

Comment: @Dre - I made some code corrections. Would be great if you can re-try using the latest code in my response.

Comment: Got it to work using your method, thank you so much. Curious to know the difference between your recommendation and the other comments.

Comment: I think the other recommendation from GME is based on "DISTINCT ON" which I guess you were trying as well. "DISTINCT ON" is something unique to PostgreSQL. My approach is based on windows function which is more generic across RDBMS btw @GMB is a master of windows function himself but probably he tried to solve it in the approach that you were attempting in your code.

Comment: Understood! I will stick with the Distinct method for now and keep in mind of yours. thanks again.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Dre & GMB. @Dre - sorry for the to and fro, I wasn’t aware of this. Would be great if could accept GMB’s answer since that’s what you are using. Thanks!!